# Align text in Owner Drawn Panels of TStatusBar in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I need to change the font color of a couple of my StatusBar panels, therefore I am using the DrawPanel event of the StatusBar. However, I need to Right Align the last two panels. Is this possible?

```
procedure TfrmMain.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
begin
 StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
 StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
 StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
 StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
 if Panel.Index = 2 then
 begin
  StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,Rect.Left,Rect.Top, 'TOTALS:');
 end;
 if Panel.Index = 3 then
 begin
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,Rect.Left,Rect.Top, TotalQty);
 end;
 if Panel.Index = 4 then
 begin
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,Rect.Left,Rect.Top, TotalStr);
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Delphi, `TCanvas` has an overloaded `TextRect()` method that accepts a `TextFormat` parameter as input:

```
procedure TfrmMain.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
begin
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  case Panel.Index of
    2: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, 'TOTALS:');
    end;
    3: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, TotalQty, [tfRight]);
    end;
    4: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, TotalStr, [tfRight]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In FreePascal, `TCanvas` has an overloaded `TextRect()` method that accepts a `Style` parameter as input:

```
procedure TfrmMain.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
var
  Style: TTextStyle;
begin
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  case Panel.Index of
    2: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, 'TOTALS:');
    end;
    3: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      Style.Alignment := taRightJustify;
      // set other Style settings as needed...
      StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, TotalQty, Style);
    end;
    4: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      Style.Alignment := taRightJustify;
      // set other Style settings as needed...
      StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, TotalStr, Style);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you are using a version of Delphi/FreePascal that does not have those parameters, you will have to use the Win32 API `DrawText()` function directly instead:

```
procedure TfrmMain.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
var
  TextRect: TRect;
begin
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
  StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  case Panel.Index of
    2: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, 'TOTALS:');
    end;
    3: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      TextRect := Rect;
      DrawText(StatusBar.Canvas.Handle, PChar(TotalQty), Length(TotalQty), TextRect, DT_RIGHT);
      // alternatively, to avoid making a copy:
      //DrawText(..., PRect(@Rect)^, ...);
    end;
    4: begin
      StatusBar.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      TextRect := Rect;
      DrawText(StatusBar.Canvas.Handle, PChar(TotalStr), Length(TotalStr), TextRect, DT_RIGHT);
      // alternatively, to avoid making a copy:
      //DrawText(..., PRect(@Rect)^, ...);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I do have that overloaded version with the style parameter, however, when I apply the Style, I then lose all the Canvas Font formatting I did and the background changed to white

Comment: Your answer works, except that Rect is a Const and it rrequires a Var. So, you need to declar a local var (e.g.  TextRect: TRect) and then assign the const  Rect parameters value to the local variable, and pass that instead - e.g. .... TextRect, DT_RIGHT);

Comment: Instead of making a copy, you can alternatively take a pointer to the `const` Rect and deference it, that would strip off the `const`, eg:  `..., PRect(@Rect)^, DT_RIGHT);`

Comment: Great, I will give that a go. Thanks!